# In Emacs split windows, how to browse the other window?

Tags: emacs

I used C-x 3 to split to left and right windows. The cursor is in left window and I can use C-n, C-p to move the cursor. How can I stay in the left window and move the code in right window up and down?

I have done this before but I lost all my emacs files. So I cannot figure it out right now. Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't already set up a good backup system, I recommend setting up a remote repository somewhere for your emacs config (e.g. github), and making sure you keep it up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've googled for the answer, [Re: How to scroll other window backwards? C-M-v does forwards](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2010-12/msg02096.html)

Still, use `scroll-other-window` function and add parameters to it. Below are the details:

```
(defun scroll-other-window-up-line ()
  "Scroll the other window one line up."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-other-window -1))
(defun scroll-other-window-down-line ()
  "Scroll the other window one line down."
  (interactive)
  (scroll-other-window 1))
(global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'scroll-other-window-up-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-n") 'scroll-other-window-down-line)
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks. This is the same thing I used before. I didn't bind to `M-p`, `M-n` though.

Answer (score 1):

`scroll-other-window` is your friend, bound to `C-M-v` by default.

Comment: C-M-v is good but it moves one page. In my former experience, I could browse line by line, just like C-n, C-p in current window.

Comment: I was hoping you will be able to use this info to do other similar things.